# Can SSH to Raspberry Pi from External IP but not Internal IP

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

So a bit of an odd issue here. I was able to SSH for the longest time both internally and externally. Come to find my SSH was locked out due to a brute force attack. Got fail2ban, reset pam_tally and found I can still SSH to my external IP but not internally. The SSH service is running and is as follows:

[image: Terminal scree grab]

I am thinking it might be a key issue (too many keys) or I am still getting locked out somehow. When I try to ping the Raspberry Pi from my laptop I get a "Destination Host Unreachable" error.

The most recent IP to try and connect was from France.

A non-standard port for ssh is the next step after Fail2Ban but I want to solve this internal issue first. In the meantime I'll disable outside SSH access.